# How do I start two thread teams with different thread functions at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have two groups of threads, one group is executed by n threads and the other is executed by m threads. I want to start them at the same time, but what I get is, that group 1 starts first, then group 2.

```
//group 1   
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(n)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        function1(i);
    }
}
//group 2   
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(m)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        function2(i);
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
function1 is called
function1 is called
function1 is called
...
n
function2 is called
...
m
```

The output I expect (just a random example):

```
function2 is called
function2 is called
function1 is called
function2 is called
function1 is called
...
```

Comment: If only there was some construct that let you specify a number of things to do and that did them all at the same time, some kind of parallel loop that you could use.

Comment: This is going to depend heavily on things like the time slice of the scheduler your OS is using and if you are using multiple cores and lots of things you probably don't want to deal with. You should ask the question, why do you want it to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, the behaviour you experience is exactly what one would expect since the 2 `parallel` regions are created sequentially one after the next.

If you want to stick with your approach of using `parallel for` constructs, you'll need to enclose them into another `parallel` construct and also allow for nested parallelism. That could give this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void function1( int i ) {
    printf( "Function1( %d )\n", i );
    usleep( ( i * 1237 + 8765 ) % 9797 );
}

void function2( int i ) {
    printf( "Function2( %d )\n", i );
    usleep( ( i * 7321 + 5678 ) % 10903 );
}

int main() {

    int n = 10, m = 5;
    omp_set_nested( 1 );

    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads( 2 )
    {
        #pragma omp section
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads( n )
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            function1( i );
        #pragma omp section
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads( m )
        for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ )
            function2( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

NB: I've added some pseudo random waiting inside the function calls to allow for some delays in returning, otherwise, the likelihood of seeing mangled output is very slim.

On my quad core machine, this gives me (for example):

```
~/tmp$ gcc -fopenmp pools.c
~/tmp$ ./a.out 
Function2( 2 )
Function1( 5 )
Function1( 1 )
Function2( 1 )
Function2( 0 )
Function1( 0 )
Function1( 3 )
Function1( 4 )
Function1( 6 )
Function1( 9 )
Function1( 7 )
Function2( 4 )
Function1( 2 )
Function1( 8 )
Function2( 3 )
```

So this answers your direct question, but I've got the feeling that the initial approach might not be the most appropriate one. You should definitively consider having a look at the `task` construct as it might be much better suited to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Gilles answer is good, but I'd like to throw some extra ideas in:

Since you have a 1 to 1 mapping from threads to functions, there is a very short solution:

```
#pragma omp parallel number_threads(n + m)
{
  assert(omp_get_num_threads() == n + m);
  auto me = omp_get_thread_num();
  if (me < n) function1(me);
  else function2(me - n);
}
```

However - in any case I suggest caution. It can be very dangerous in terms of performance to have more threads than cores (oversubscription), and would rather leave the choice of thread count to OpenMP, and there is still a simple solution without nesting:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int nm = 0; nm < n + m; nm++) {
  if (nm < n) function1(nm);
  else function2(nm - n);
}
```